# $J^{PC}$ quantum numbers of QED bound states

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, quantum-electrodynamics

The 3 leptons ($e,\mu,\tau$) of QED can form bound states. The positronium $e e^+$ can have spin 0 (para positronium) or spin 1 (ortho positronium). There is also muonium $e \mu^+$, true muonium $\mu \mu^+$, and similarly other bound states with $\tau$ as constituent.

What are the parities of each of these bound states? The spins and charge conjugation properties are rather clear, so in the $J^{PC}$ notation $J$ and $C$ are straightforward, but what about $P$?

Comment: Same game. All elementary fermions have an intrinsic parity +1 while antifermions have -1. Then the spin and L combinations follow suit. Blind yourself to lepton flavor.

Comment: Follow the rules in your text. P=- for the singlet para, and + for the triplet ortho. Look at the photon decays.

Comment: Right. Sorry about the ortho.. it’s also -.

Comment: Yes for the para, but the spin enters for the ortho, so $1^{-~-}$.

Comment: Because of the standard [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_parity#Multiparticle_systems) $C=(-)^{L+S}$ your text should have derived. Ortho has S=1, L=0.

Answer (score 1):

From comments of Cosmas Zachos:

$$C = (-1)^{L+S} \qquad \qquad P = (-1)^{L+1}$$

So the para positronium $(S=0, L=0)$ has $J^{PC} = 0^{-+}$ and the ortho positronium $(S=1, L=0)$ has $J^{PC} = 1^{--}$.